# How do i select an element from HTML with JQuery

Tags: jquery, html

Which selector can i use when i want to locate an element in this HTML-setup? Cant use .next because JQuery must look deeper in the HTML.

I have tried filter, find, children, but nothing works - i must be doing something wrong somewhere..

JQuery

```
$('.btn').click(function(){
        $(this).next('.show_wrap').show(100); // .next NOT WORKING
});
```

HTML

```
<div class="h1_blue">
    <div class="h1_darker"></div>
        <h1>1</h1>
            <div class="btn" style="float: right"> SHOW </div>  
</div> <!--END OF h1_blue - THIS IS NEXT IN JQUERY ?? -->
<div class="pre_hide"> 
    <div class="show_wrap">
        <h1> content 1 </h1> 
    </div> <!-- END OF show_wrap -->    
</div> 

<div class="h1_blue">
    <div class="h1_darker"></div>
        <h1>2</h1>
            <div class="btn" style="float: right"> SHOW </div>  
</div> <!--END OF h1_blue - THIS IS NEXT IN JQUERY ?? -->
<div class="pre_hide"> 
    <div class="show_wrap">
        <h1> content 2 </h1> 
    </div> <!-- END OF show_wrap -->    
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using wrong combination of jquery selectors. Use:

```
 $('.btn').click(function(){ 
  $(this).closest('.h1_blue').next().find('.show_wrap').show(100); 
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
$('.btn').click(function(){
    $(this).closest('.h1_blue').next().find('.show_wrap').show(100);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work -

```
$('.btn').click(function(){
     $(this).closest('div.h1_blue').next().find('.show_wrap').show(100);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

try

```
$('.btn').click(function(){
    $(this).parents(".h1_blue").next().find('.show_wrap').show(100); // .next NOT WORKING
});
```